# CSS relative positioned list elements. Reset withing media query for mobile

Tags: css, imagemap, css-position

I have an imagemap on my website which unfortunately is too big for the mobile version.

As such I have decided to use css media queries such that if the screen is smaller than the map, it simply displays a list instead.

The image map mouseover overlay works with a list whereby the overlays are positioned relatively.

In my media query I thus want to reset the relative positioning so the list items simply appear one below each other like a normal list.

How would I go about this? At the moment the list items simply appear scattered around the page where they would appear if they still had their respective image backgrounds.

THanks

Comment: Are you using a `<map>` element? I kindly suggest you read http://www.alistapart.com/articles/imagemap/.

Comment: wrap your existing code in a `bigger than mobile` query

Comment: A lot of people advocate "mobile first": "mobile" as the default and use media queries for wider devices.  Setting a bunch of styling only to undo it elsewhere isn't very practical.